# On some theorems involving universal quantifiers and variable capture in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In Richard E Hodel's textbook *Mathematical Logic* (Example 5, p.149) where $A$ stands for any formula, it is proven that $(\forall x_n A) \to A$ is logically valid, where $A$ is a formula of a first-order language $L$ and where a formula of $L$ is *logically valid* if and only if $A$ is true in all interpretations of $L$ with respect to all variable assignments.

I'm a bit confused about the status of this theorem, since, I've only ever seen it claimed (in other textbooks on mathematical logic) that if $\tau$ is substitutable for $x$, then $(\forall x_n \phi(x)) \to \phi(\tau)$, or that $(\forall x_n \phi(x)) \to \phi(x)$ holds, where $x$ occurs free in the consequent. Later in the text (Theorem 4 (Logical validity of substitution axioms), p.163), Hodel states something like $(\forall x_n \phi(x)) \to \phi(\tau)$ as his *Theorem 4 (Logical validity of substitution axioms)*, p.163.

How does the theorem that $(\forall x_n A) \to A$ is logically valid relate to these other theorems? It is not transparent to me, especially since the other theorems mentioned make restrictions based on whether a term is substitutable for another. This makes me wonder whether Hodel made a mistake and missed out a similar condition.

I would be delighted if you could help clarify these issues.

---

I have subsequently seen that in the axiom system Hodel introduces (p.168, op cit), $(\forall x_n A) \to A_{x_n}[t]$ and $(\forall x_n A) \to A$ are classified as "substitution axioms", with the latter called a special case and with $A_{x_n}[t]$ being the formula obtained from $A$ by replacing every occurrence of $x$ in $A$ with $t$. He remarks that if $(\forall x_n A) \to A_{x_n}[t]$ is called a *substitution axiom*, then

> the formula $(\forall x_n A) \to A$ is always a substitution axiom; this is so since $x_n$ is substitutable for $x_n$ in any formula and $A_{x_n}[x_n]$ is just $A$.''

I find this confusing since he does not seem to define the notation $A_{x_n}[x_n]$ for the case when $A$ is a propositional variable (unless the definition he gives for the case $R(u,...,v)$ is supposed to implicitly cover the case of 0-ary relation symbols). Without covering the case of propositional variables, I can't see how the claim that $A_{x_n}[x_n]$ is just $A$ can be made, when $A$ is a propositional variable.

Comment: It's the same theorem, but the variable is often omitted in the notation, hence $A$ instead of $A(t)$

Comment: I can't see how it can be. Derek Goldrei's proof of the theorem $(\forall x_n \phi(x)) \to \phi(\tau)$ in his book *Propositional and Predicate Calculus* (P.172-2) is much more complicated than the few lines Hodel gives to prove $(\forall x_n A) \to A$ and adverts specifically to facts about substitutability (which Hodel doesn't even mention).

Comment: Maybe you have to check with the details of the syntax... maybe $A$ means that there is not $x$ free in it.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA It doesn't seem so. I've checked.

Comment: Ok but in general if $\forall x A$ is true, so must be $A$.

Comment: If x is free in A apply theorem with x as t; if not, the result is obvious.

Comment: But why does the proof of the logical validity of $(\forall x_n A) \to A$ not utilise induction on the structure of formulas, given that $A$ is standing for an arbitrary formula?

Comment: If you have Th.4 above, the only thing to note is thT$A_x[x]$ is $A$ itself.